# Building Dynamic array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm pulling results from an XML SOAP service which returns results in structure that doesn't work too well with encoding the result to json then decoding into an array.

Here's an example of the output I've rendered by running the following function on my results:

```
$result[implode('/',$keys)] = $val;



Array
(
    [accountList/accountNo] => 0610010000048744
    [accountList/accountOpeningDate] => 2014-09-01T00:00:00+03:00
    [accountList/accountStatus] => DORMANT
    [accountList/arrearAmount] => 80000.0
    [accountList/arrearDays] => 30
    [accountList/balanceAmount] => 120000.0
    [accountList/disputed] => false
    [accountList/isMyAccount] => false
    [accountList/lastPaymentDate] => 2015-01-23T00:00:00+03:00
    [accountList/listingDate] => 2014-09-30T00:00:00+03:00
    [accountList/pastDueDate] => 1900-01-01T00:00:00+03:00
    [accountList/principalAmount] => 300000.0
    [accountList/scheduledPaymentAmount] => 0.0
    [accountList/tradeSector] => Bank Sector Bureau
    [accountList/worstArrear] => 30
    [accountList/currency] => KES
    [personalProfile/crn] => 79908
    [personalProfile/dateOfBirth] => 1959-01-01T00:00:00+02:45
    [personalProfile/fullName] => Surname 79908 OtherNames 79908
    [personalProfile/gender] => F
    [personalProfile/nationalID] => ID79908
    [summary/npaAccounts/mySector] => 2
    [summary/npaAccounts/otherSectors] => 0
    [summary/npaTotalValueList/currency] => KES
    [summary/npaTotalValueList/mySector] => 120000.0
    [summary/npaTotalValueList/otherSectors] => 0.0
    [summary/openAccounts/mySector] => 2
    [summary/openAccounts/otherSectors] => 0
)
```

Because the results and keys always vary depending on request I make to the server, I'd like to build a multidimensional array through a recursive function, in some instances the keys eg. accountList may have multiple values

An expected result would look something like this:

```
Array
(


   [accountList] => Array
        (
            [accountNo] => 0610010000048744
            [accountOpeningDate] => 2014-09-01T00:00:00+03:00
            [accountStatus] => DORMANT
            [arrearAmount] => 80000.0
            [arrearDays] => 30
            [balanceAmount] => 120000.0
            [disputed] => false
            [isMyAccount] => false
            [lastPaymentDate] => 2015-01-23T00:00:00+03:00
            [listingDate] => 2014-09-30T00:00:00+03:00
            [pastDueDate] => 1900-01-01T00:00:00+03:00
            [principalAmount] => 300000.0
            [scheduledPaymentAmount] => 0.0
            [tradeSector] => Bank, Sector Bureau
            [worstArrear] => 30
            [currency] => KES
        )
    Array
    (
        [accountNo] => 0610010000048788
        [accountOpeningDate] => 2014-09-01T00:00:00+03:00
        [accountStatus] => ACTIVE
        [arrearAmount] => 10000.0
        [arrearDays] => 90
        [balanceAmount] => 10000.0
        [disputed] => TRUE
        [isMyAccount] => false
        [lastPaymentDate] => 2015-01-23T00:00:00+03:00
        [listingDate] => 2014-09-30T00:00:00+03:00
        [pastDueDate] => 1900-01-01T00:00:00+03:00
        [principalAmount] => 300000.0
        [scheduledPaymentAmount] => 0.0
        [tradeSector] => Bank, Sector Bureau
        [worstArrear] => 30
        [currency] => KES
    )

    [personalProfile] => Array
        (
            [crn] => 79908
            [dateOfBirth] => 1959-01-01T00:00:00+02:45
            [fullName] => Surname, 79908 OtherNames 79908
            [gender] => F
            [nationalID] => ID79908
        )

)
```

Comment: Umm, can you give an `$val` example so that we can test about?

Comment: Can you add an example of what the resulting array would contain based on what you have above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to achieve this thing.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/777065)

`explode("/", $key)` this will return array which will contain two values.

`list($first,$second)=explode("/", $key);` and through this i am putting those values, one in `$first` and other in `$second`.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$data=Array
(
    "accountList/accountNo"=>"0610010000048744",
    "accountList/accountOpeningDate"=>"2014-09-01T00:00:00+03:00",
    "accountList/accountStatus"=>"DORMANT",
    "accountList/arrearAmount"=>"80000.0",
    "accountList/arrearDays"=>"30",
    "accountList/balanceAmount"=>"120000.0",
    "accountList/disputed"=>"false",
    "accountList/isMyAccount"=>"false",
    "accountList/lastPaymentDate"=>"2015-01-23T00:00:00+03:00",
    "accountList/listingDate"=>"2014-09-30T00:00:00+03:00",
    "accountList/pastDueDate"=>"1900-01-01T00:00:00+03:00",
    "accountList/principalAmount"=>"300000.0",
    "accountList/scheduledPaymentAmount"=>"0.0",
    "accountList/tradeSector"=>"Bank, Sector Bureau",
    "accountList/worstArrear"=>"30",
    "accountList/currency"=>"KES",
    "personalProfile/crn"=>"79908",
    "personalProfile/dateOfBirth"=>"1959-01-01T00:00:00+02:45",
    "personalProfile/fullName"=>"Surname, 79908 OtherNames 79908",
    "personalProfile/gender"=>"F",
    "personalProfile/nationalID"=>"ID79908",
    "sample/data/data1"=>"ID79908",//added a sample data
);
$result=array();
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    $string="";
    $numberOfWords=explode("/", $key);
    foreach($numberOfWords as $newValue)
    {
        $string.="['$newValue']";
    }
    eval('$result'.$string."= \"$value\";");
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: @SloanThrasher Sure.

Comment: @Salhil: Thanks! Learned something new today.

Comment: wow, that was fast, thanks. Can this handle multiple instances of say accountList without replacing values on the first occurence?

Comment: @MasindeMuliro Yes try the code snippet. and check whether you are expecting this or not.

Comment: I am getting an Notice: Undefined offset: 1 on this line  list($first,$second) = explode("/", $key);

I've checked the $key and it's fine which is word because your snippet seems to work fine

Comment: @MasindeMuliro Are you using the same array which is in the post?

Comment: @SahilGulati yes I have. I've made an edit to my values. The keys are totally dynamic and in some instances, we have more than two strings for example ` [summary/npaAccounts/mySector] => 2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141806/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-masinde-muliro).

Answer (score 0):

The way you want to build your array is as follows. The reason is that you want things like "accountList" and "personalProfile" to be unique keys within the array, much like they would be in a relational database.

```
$array = $array('accountList'=>array("accountNo"=>"0610010000048744", 
"accountOpenDate"=>"2014-09-
01T00:00:00+03:00"),array("personalProfile"=>array("...and so on."));
```

Comment: They keys are dynamic depending on function call so this may not work